# Flutter web, update navbar after authorization

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to create a web application using flutter and I have a question. After I go through authorization, I need to change the "login" button in the navbar, as I understand it, I need to change the button text and call setState in my navbar, but in my implementation an exception is thrown.

AuthPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:um/pages/home/app_color.dart';
import 'package:um/scripts/api_client.dart';
import 'package:um/scripts/locator.dart';

import 'NavBarDesktop.dart';

class AuthorizationPageDesktop extends StatefulWidget {
  AuthorizationPageDesktop({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthorizationPageDesktopState createState() =>
      _AuthorizationPageDesktopState();
}

class _AuthorizationPageDesktopState extends State<AuthorizationPageDesktop> {
  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool rememberMe = false;
  ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient.getInstance();
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 0, right: 0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Авторизация',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 28,
                color: textPrimaryColor),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          _input(Icon(Icons.mail), 'Email', _emailController, false, 15),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          _input(Icon(Icons.lock), 'Password', _passwordController, true, 15),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
              width: 460,
              child: Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(
                      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                      hoverColor: Colors.transparent),
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Запомнить меня',
                      style: TextStyle(color: textPrimaryColor),
                    ),
                    value: rememberMe,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        rememberMe = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ))),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          _button('Войти', auth, 15),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 460,
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Пройдите ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'регистрацию, ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: linkColor, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'если вы этого еще не сделали',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }

  Widget _input(Icon icon, String hint, TextEditingController controller,
      bool obscure, double borderRadius) {
    return Container(
      width: 460,
      height: 50,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscure,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            isDense: true, // Added this
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8), //

            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
            hintText: hint,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2)),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54, width: 1)),
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              child: IconTheme(
                data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                child: icon,
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _button(String label, void func(), double borderRadius) {
    return Container(
        width: 460,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            apiClient
                .authorization(_emailController.text, _passwordController.text)
                .then((value) {
              func();
            });
          },
          highlightColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          color: buttonPrimaryColor,
          child: Text('Войти',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: textPrimaryColor,
                  fontSize: 16)),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius)),
        ));
  }

  void auth() {
    var state = navBar<NavBarDesktop>().navBarState;
    state.update();
  }
}
```

NavBar.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:um/Widgets/Desktop/AuthPageDesktop.dart';
import 'package:um/Widgets/Desktop/HomePageDesktop.dart';
import 'package:um/Widgets/NavBarItem.dart';
import 'package:um/layout_template/layout_template.dart';
import 'package:um/pages/home/app_color.dart';
import 'package:um/scripts/api_client.dart';
import 'package:um/scripts/locator.dart';

class NavBarDesktop extends StatefulWidget {
  NavBarDesktop({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  GlobalKey<_NavBarDesktopState> navBarDesktop =
      GlobalKey<_NavBarDesktopState>();

  _NavBarDesktopState navBarState = new _NavBarDesktopState();

  static _NavBarDesktopState of(BuildContext context) {
    // print('_NavBarDesktopState -> ${context}');
    assert(context != null);
    final _NavBarDesktopState result =
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_NavBarDesktopState>());
    // print('_NavBarDesktopState resutl -> ${result}');
    return result;
  }

  @override
  _NavBarDesktopState createState() => new _NavBarDesktopState();
}

class _NavBarDesktopState extends State<NavBarDesktop> {
  String authButtonTitle = "Войти";

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('call init state navbar ${ApiClient.username}');
    if (ApiClient.username != null && ApiClient.username.length > 0)
      authButtonTitle = ApiClient.username;
    super.initState();
  }

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      authButtonTitle = ApiClient.username;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: primaryColor,
      height: 50,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                LayoutTemplate.of(context).change_page(HomePageDesktop());
              },
              child: Text(
                'UM',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: textPrimaryColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 40),
              )),
          NavBarItem(
              authButtonTitle,
              () => LayoutTemplate.of(context)
                  .change_page(AuthorizationPageDesktop())),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void auth_page_up(BuildContext context) {
    LayoutTemplate.of(context).change_page(AuthorizationPageDesktop());
  }
}
```

Exception

```
Error: setState() called in constructor: _NavBarDesktopState#5e1ee(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to   
call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:4334:11)
    at http://localhost:50572/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:13615:23
    at NavBarDesktop._NavBarDesktopState.new.setState (http://localhost:50572/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:13618:26)      
    at NavBarDesktop._NavBarDesktopState.new.update (http://localhost:50572/packages/um/scripts/router.dart.lib.js:1717:12)
    at AuthPageDesktop._AuthorizationPageDesktopState.new.auth (http://localhost:50572/packages/um/scripts/router.dart.lib.js:1932:13)
    at http://localhost:50572/packages/um/scripts/router.dart.lib.js:1926:15
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:37457:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:32441:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:32988:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:33026:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:32869:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:32891:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:37718:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:37724:13)
    at http://localhost:50572/dart_sdk.js:33243:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your _NavBarDesktopState global key needs to be initialized in your _NavBarDesktopState class., not the NavBarDesktop class.  It's trying to set the global key before the state has even been created.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NavBarDesktop extends StatefulWidget {
  NavBarDesktop({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _NavBarDesktopState navBarState;

  static _NavBarDesktopState of(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final _NavBarDesktopState result =
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<_NavBarDesktopState>());
    return result;
  }

  @override
  _NavBarDesktopState createState() {
    navBar.registerLazySingleton(() => this);
    navBarState = _NavBarDesktopState();
    return navBarState;
  }
}
```